# Highcharts series visibility with csv data source

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am new to programming language so please consider my poor knowledge. Basically i am trying to use Highcharts for my project which takes data from a csv data source.
please take a look at:
[flood forcast data](http://vamphim.com/highchart/chart.php)

The chart shows 10 days flood forcast for a particular place. I want to have the ability to disable a data series by default, so that when you click on its legend item it shows, instead of hides. This will give me the ability to put many series on one graph, only show the Important ones, while allowing users to show additional series if they need. as an example: on load it will have day1, day3 and day5 "visible: true" and rest "visible: false."  hope i made it clear

here goes my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js">       </script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Flood Forecast</title>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {

           $.get('data.csv', function(csv) {
            // Create the chart
            window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type:'spline'
                },

                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 1,
                    inputDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'

                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Flood Forcast'
                },

                legend: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    borderWidth: 0.5,
                    itemDistance: 0
                },

               // data
                data: {
                    csv: csv
                },


            }, function(chart) {
                // apply the date pickers
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#' + chart.options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker()
                }, 0)
            });
        });

        // Set the datepicker's date format
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function(dateText) {
                this.onchange();
                this.onblur();
            }
        });

    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 600px; min-width: 600px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the visible property, just add to your options:

```
series: [{
        visible: false
    }, {
        visible: true
    }]
```

**series** represents your array of series, in this example has two series, the first hidden and the second visible. You can check this fiddle that uses data csv too:

http://jsfiddle.net/u4yaxk58/

Hope it helps!